# javascript - onclick of anything but certain elements; e.target not working... sometimes

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to recreate **jQuery**'s native `event` handler, `.click("body", "element, element", function( ... ));`. Where if the user clicks on anything but those two elements, it will do something.

I've successfully done this, however, sometimes the script **will not work**. After a while, if the user clicks on the `body`, then the actual dropdown button trigger, it will not toggle the `class` for the dropdown. I'm unsure why this is happening, because it is working every now and then...

---

This is my **JavaScript**:

```
var uButton = document.getElementById("user_content"), // the trigger
    uDropdown = document.getElementById("user__dropdown-menu"); // the menu

document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target == uButton){ // if button has been clicked
        toggleClass(uDropdown, "active"); // (custom function) toggle the class "active"
    } else if(e.target != uButton && e.target != uDropdown){ // if anything BUT the dropdown and button are clicked
        if(hasClass(uDropdown, "active")){ // (custom function) if the dropdown is active
            uDropdown.className = "user__procedural-outer-dropdown"; // reset the classes to default
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding **HTML**:

```
<div class="navigation__user-content" id="user_content"> <!-- the button !-->
    <span id="nav_username">Sign In</span>
    <div class="user__procedural-outer"></div>
</div>
<div class="user__procedural-outer-dropdown" id="user__dropdown-menu"></div> <!-- dropdown !-->
```

---

I've included a [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/auqumd7s/1/) to so you can **try** and recreate my problem.

All help is greatly appreciated,  
Thanks.

Comment: adding a simple `console.log(e.target)`, you can see that the target is sometimes `<span id="nav_username">Sign In</span>`

Comment: @Claies how would I make sure that it works when it hits the button or the content within? I've tried `uButton = document.querySelector("#user_content, #user_content *);` However, it still only works sometimes

Comment: I believe the issue is the fact that there are nested HTML elements. The target is supposed to be the innermost nested element. I believe the solution would be a do...while loop with the condition `(elem = elem.parentNode)`.

Comment: @JonathanGray mind posting an answer? :) still new to raw **JavaScript**, so I would have no idea how to do that.. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I modified your code as minimally as possible.</s> I hope this is what you're looking for.

```js
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
function toggleClass(element, cls){
 element.classList.toggle(cls);
}

var uButton = document.getElementById("user_content"), // the trigger
    uDropdown = document.getElementById("user__dropdown-menu"); // the menu

document.onclick = function(e){
  var elem = e.target;
  do {
      switch(elem) {
        case uButton:
          return toggleClass(uDropdown, "active");
        case uDropdown:
          return void(0);
        }
     }
  while(elem = elem.parentNode);
  if(hasClass(uDropdown, "active"))
    uDropdown.className = "user__procedural-outer-dropdown";
}
```

```css
.navigation__user-content{
 width: 70px;
 height: 15px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 padding: 8px;
 float: right;
 background: #730aa2;
 border-radius: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.navigation__user-content:hover{
 box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px #5a0d91;
}
.navigation__user-content:hover #nav_username{
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #5a0d91;
}
.navigation__user-content > #nav_username{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 top: -2px;
 left: 3px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}
.user__procedural-outer{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: -2px;
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 border-radius: 16px;
 background: url("noimagefound.png") no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
}
.user__procedural-outer-dropdown{
 position: absolute;
 top: 43px;
 right: 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.user__procedural-outer-dropdown.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation__user-content" id="user_content">
  <span id="nav_username">Sign In</span>
  <div class="user__procedural-outer"></div>
</div>
<div class="user__procedural-outer-dropdown" id="user__dropdown-menu"></div>
```

Comment: I know it might be a big ask, but mind explaining how it works through comments? I'm still new to JS and would really appreciate it, if you could! :)

Comment: @Caelan. I went back over the code and realised something that I actually missed. I decided to modify my answer to make use of a feature which better addresses the problem and makes the algorithm actually perform what it's intended to do more accurately. I hope it's clear enough for you to understand.

Comment: You're new solution semi-works, the only problem is that when the dropdown is clicked on, it disappears, it should only be the button and the body. you're older version works, however :)

Comment: @Caelan. It works for me, and I don't see why it wouldn't work for you. What browser are you testing with? I changed my solution so that you can have elements inside of the dropdown without it interfering with the logic. So even though my previous solution technically worked with the specific implementation it still had very limited use.

Comment: I'm using Chrome v55 and Firefox v50.0.1. I dunno, I'll try testing again

Comment: Ok, so I tried testing again and.. Whenever the use clicks on and element within the dropdown menu, it disappears.. :/ how would I fix this? thanks

Comment: @Caelan. That's exactly what my new code is supposed to fix. But apparently it's not working for you at all? I'll download Firefox when I get a chance to test it.

Comment: @Caelan. I just tested with Chrome 55.0.2883.87 and Firefox 50.1.0 and they both seem to work properly. Also tested with Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0. It all seems to work fine. I almost wonder if maybe you have some sort of adware or malware that may be injecting additional code messing with things? I don't know why it works for me but not for you. Perhaps you missed the edit to the array `var elems = [uButton, uDropdown];` or something similar?

Comment: Is it supposed to work with clicking on elements **WITHIN** the dropdown?

Comment: @Caelan. Yes, I understand what you are asking for, and it is supposed to work as intended. At least it does for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132660/discussion-between-jonathan-gray-and-caelan).

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are several problems here. i renamed the class names to more simple words and test the code. i found, based on your css and what you set as position:relative and position:absolute, the dropdown-menu div must be inside the user_...-outer div!

i revise the code as following and test it. it works without problem:

```js
var uButton = document.getElementById("user_content"),
    uDropdown = document.getElementById("user-dropdown");

document.onclick = function (e) {

  if (e.target == uButton || e.target.parentNode == uButton) {
    toggleClass(uDropdown, "active");
  } else if (e.target != uButton && e.target != uDropdown) {
    if (hasClass(uDropdown, "active")) {
      uDropdown.className = "user-dropdown";
    }
  }
}


function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
function toggleClass(element, cls) {
  element.classList.toggle(cls);
}
```

```css
.user-content{
 width: 70px;
 height: 15px;
 margin-top: 6px;
 padding: 8px;
 float: right;
 background: #730aa2;
 border-radius: 2px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.user-content:hover{
 box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0 #200050;
}
.user-content > #signin{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 top: -2px;
 left: 3px;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}
.user-content:hover > #signin{
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #caca30;
}
.user-outer{
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: -2px;
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 border-radius: 16px;
 background: yellow no-repeat center;
 background-size: cover;
}
.user-dropdown{
 position: absolute;
 top: 43px;
 right: 0;
 width: 320px;
 height: 200px;
    /*background:#f8f8f8;*/ /* to see its position*/
    visibility: hidden; /* hide when not active */
 overflow: hidden;
}
.user-dropdown.active{
  background: red;
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a test page!</p>

<div id="user_content" class="user-content">
  <span id="signin">Sign In</span>
  <div id="user-outer" class="user-outer">
    <div id="user-dropdown" class="user-dropdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**
use `if (e.target == uButton || e.target.parentNode == uButton)` in click event to include all elements inside button to show the dropdown.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over what the classes are called, so I'm kinda stuck with them haha

Answer (score 1):

since your `nav_username` is not in the `user__procedural-outer`, you need to target it also when `document.onclick = function(e)` happens

```
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
function toggleClass(element, cls){
    element.classList.toggle(cls);
}

var uButton = document.getElementById("user_content"),
    uButtonSpan = document.getElementById("nav_username"),
    /*since your "nav_username" is not in the "user__procedural-outer", you need to target it also when "document.onclick = function(e)" happens */
    uDropdown = document.getElementById("user__dropdown-menu");

document.onclick = function(e){
    if((e.target == uButton) || (e.target == uButtonSpan)){
        toggleClass(uDropdown, "active");
    } else if((e.target != uDropdown) && (e.target != uButtonSpan) && (hasClass(uDropdown, "active"))){
            uDropdown.className = "user__procedural-outer-dropdown";
    }
}
```